# Change page transition animation in Xamarin Forms with Prism

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

Is it possible to change page transition animation in Xamarin Forms with Prism's INavigationService? I'd like to have fade animation on Android, like when using default Xamarin Forms PushAsync/PopAsync mechanism, or at least left/right sliding instead of up/down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prism uses Xamarin.Forms built-in PushAsync/PopAsync methods.  This also means it uses the default XF animations automatically.  If you want custom animations, this is not something that Prism is not responsible for.

Now building custom page transitions in XF isn't very clear cut.  Here are a couple of links that should get you going in the ight direction.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18818/custom-page-transitions-with-xamarin-forms/p1

https://kernel32.net/2016/06/25/xamarin-forms-transitions.html

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I've already seen those links. For some reason PushAsync/PopAsync gives me fade transition, while INavigationService results in slide up/down animations. I'll try to investigate further. Anyway, thanks for answer