# PRISM - CustomRenderer for NavigationPage

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I would like to ask if creating a custom renderer for `NavigationPage` would override Prism's `NavigationService`? since as per [CustomPageTransition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549176/change-page-transition-animation-in-xamarin-forms-with-prism) Prism uses Xamarin's built-in PushAsync/PopAsync -- correct me if I am wrong, this is the `Navigation.PushAsync(page)` right?

Thanks!

Comment: Navigation.PuchAsync(new (pagename))

Comment: @HashirMalik Yes, I am quite well aware of it, but that's not the point of my question.